# Convert WMI Creationdate in Format-Table

Tags: powershell, datetime, wmi

I'm trying to get all `svchost` processes from my machine into a nicely formatted table, containing a formatted datetime but so far have failed to do so.

This is how I get all the processes into an array

```psh
$processes = @(gwmi -cl Win32_Process -f "name='svchost.exe'")
```

and following prints the datetime as I'd like it them *but as a list*

```
$processes | % {$_.Caption, $_.ConvertToDateTime($_.CreationDate)} 
svchost.exe
vrijdag 4 september 2015 20:47:03
svchost.exe
vrijdag 4 september 2015 20:47:03
svchost.exe
```

while following prints the statements as I'd like them as a table *but without the formatting of the datetime*

```
$processes | ft Caption, CreationDate -a
Caption     CreationDate             
-------     ------------             
svchost.exe 20150904204703.429503+120
svchost.exe 20150904204703.861565+120
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to print it as

```
Caption     CreationDate             
-------     ------------             
svchost.exe vrijdag 4 september 2015 20:47:03
svchost.exe vrijdag 4 september 2015 20:47:03
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Select-Object` instead of `ForEach-Object`. That allows you to select specific properties of your objects and also to add [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx):

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "name='svchost.exe'" | 
  Select-Object Caption,
                @{n='CreationDate'; e={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.CreationDate)}}
```

If you want to do this with `ForEach-Object` you'll have to create new objects:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "name='svchost.exe'" | 
  ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
      'Caption'      = $_.Caption
      'CreationDate' = $_.ConvertToDateTime($_.CreationDate)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar. Exactly what I needed.