# String to Array in PowerShell (with no delimiters)

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, formatting

I'm trying to use WMI to get the start times of a computer's login sessions using:

```bsh
$starttimes = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogonSession -ComputerName HM-ITS-KLP |
              select starttime
```

This gives me the date formatted as:

```
20170120075444.819609+000 (yyyymmddhhmmss.??????+???)
```

Using the `String.ToCharArray()` method I managed to convert a string to an array so that I could restructure it better, although in this format it will not accept this as:

> Method invocation failed because [Selected.System.Management.ManagementObject] doesn't contain a method named 'ToCharArray'.

Whole code as follows:

```bsh
$starttimes = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogonSession -ComputerName HM-ITS-KLP |
              select StartTime
foreach ($line in $starttimes) {
  $dateArray = $line.ToCharArray()
  $time = $dateArray[8..9] + ":" + $dateArray[10..11] + ":" + $dateArray[12..13]
  $date = $dateArray[6..7] + "/" + $dateArray[4..5] + "/" + $dateArray[0..3]
  $LoginTimeAndDate1 = $time + "  " + $date
  $LoginTimeAndDate = $LoginTimeAndDate1 -join ""
}
```

Comment: I would *strongly* recommend [converting the strings to actual `DateTime` values](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32548960/1630171) rather than messing around with character arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to expand the "starttime" property. Try change to this:

```
foreach ( $line in $starttimes){
$dateArray = $line.starttime.toCharArray()
```

or this:

```
foreach ( $line in $starttimes.starttime){
$dateArray = $line.toCharArray()
```

or this:

```
$starttimes = Get-WMIObject Win32_LogonSession |  select -Expand starttime
foreach ( $line in $starttimes){
```

Comment: Thankyou very much, solved my problem straight away!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogonSession -ComputerName "HM-ITS-KLP" | select  @{N='starttime';E={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.starttime)}}
```